# How to enable iptables with verbose mode in DD-WRT?

Tags: logging, dd-wrt, iptables

I want to log all packets to messages through iptables. Can you help me how to set verbose mode in DD-WRT. Just DYI, I have optware installed to store the large messages file and do log rotation.